# Ever with simple present

Tags: grammar

Quote from "Slaughterhouse five"
 novel

My boss was one of the toughest guys I ever hope to meet.

I know tense in the sentence determine s the scope of "ever".so that means he wants to say that he hopes to meet tough guys in future but didn't hoped in past or present.It looks kind of weird to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean what you suppose.

If you analyse the context:

His boss was a very tough person
He worked for this person
Presumably, because this person was so tough, he didn't enjoy working for him
He probably had a very tough time as an employee
So he never wants to meet anyone like his boss
and certainly not to work for such a person again.

Thus what he is saying is that he never wants to meet anybody who is tougher than the boss that he used to work for.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: @ManishKumarBalayan This answer still fits with your edited question. The person does not hope to meet tough guys in the future. He just hopes that none of the tough guys he *may happen to meet* are tougher than his boss.

Answer (score 3):

The normal locution is:

> My boss was the toughest guy *I have ever met*.

The meaning is, in my life up to the present, no man has been tougher than my boss.

When we change **I have ever met** to **I ever hope to meet**, the meaning would be:

> I hope *never* to meet a guy in the future who is tougher than my boss was.

There, **tough** means "difficult to work for, very demanding, perhaps unfair in his expectations" if we apply it to "boss":

> He's a tough boss.

or if we apply it to "guy" the meaning in that context would be something like "difficult to be around, harsh, unforgiving, unfriendly" and qualities of that nature. It is not a precise adjective.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: The implied meaning is "I don't ever want to meet a *tougher* guy".  My ability to deal with toughness was maxxed out with him.  The locution does not imply a desire to meet tough guys; it's merely a way of saying "that guy was very very tough".

Comment: Why never or anything negative is not used in the sentence

Comment: This use of **ever** with a superlative is a set rhetorical pattern whose implied meaning is either "it is unsurpassed" in that regard, or at least you won't want to meet one that surpasses it.  *He's the orneriest son-of-a-bitch you'll ever want to meet* doesn't mean that you want to meet ornery sons of bitches. It means "He's damn ornery, about as ornery as ornery gets."

Comment: @ManishKumarBalayan The meaning of "I hope this is the worst ever" and "I hope there is never anything worse than this" are roughly equivalent, just like "I don't like him" and "I dislike him". Words like "never" and "not" provide *grammatical* negation, but the meaning can be negated by using words with an opposite meaning.